# Laravel TinyMCE video insert error

Tags: php, laravel, tinymce

I have problem with my laravel and TinyMCE script.
Everything works good, but in the moment when i try to insert video from YT using my script i get error:

```
406
Not Acceptable

This request is not acceptable
```

When I delete video from textarea script work normally. I think the request block

```
<iframe>
```

tag but I don't know how I can turn off it.